# Filtering one List Part, by another Web Part, where the Second web part has a filtered View

Tags: web-part, list, wss-3.0, filter

I have one list, called "Company Reports" and another list "Companies"

The Companies list has a field called Include(yes/no), and I have created a View which filters it to only show active companies.

Now when I try to connect the first list to then second to filter the Company Reports by Included companies, I always get all the Company's Reports.

In SQL this would be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CompanyReports 
INNER JOIN Companies ON CompanyReports.CompanyName = Companies.Name 
WHERE Companies.Include = 1
```

Is the WP Connection ignoring the Filter defined in the View of the Companies?

Is there any way to make it work this way?

Comment: Really can't tell what you are doing here. You would use a connection to filter another view. It seems like you are saying that your Companies list has the same companies listed more than once. The second webpart would not care how the first one is filtered.

Comment: No, Companies list is a distinct list of Companies, Reports can contain many reports for one company. I'm aiming for a more SQL like join. I've added SQL to question to try and make it clearer

Comment: I thought that was what you were trying to do, but that does  not sound right in SharePoint. If your first webpart is filtered to only show companies with "Include" set and this works, then this part is fine. The next part is to figure out the connection to the second webpart. How are you trying to "connect" them. What steps did you take?

Comment: I added a List View Web Part for Reports and a LVWP for Companies, set its view to the filtered one. Then used the Connections Wizard to connect them by a common field for "Get Sort/Filter From" action. It seems to me that WSS is ignoring the fact I have filtered(via a view) the second list

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. When you connect the webparts, are you selecting an item in the Company webpart to "filter" the Reports webpart? Did you set the Company webpart to automatically send its first Row to the Reports webpart? These are things to check. I am not sure what else you might be experiencing.